# Does Bill still have his "toe-fungus"?

Tags: plot-explanation, king-of-the-hill

In the episode *Leanne's Saga*, Bill is warned not to drink while taking medication prescribed for a form of athlete's foot- but he's seen drinking beer with his friends in later episodes- did he stop taking the meds and let the fungus continue to grow so he could drink with the guys?

Answer (score 1):

While I am not privy to exactly what you are talking about, I am aware that most fungal medications are not great on the liver, and it is not advisable to drink while taking said medications.  Having said that, it is unlikely that a writer would worry about such things, as the dos and don't of fungal medication are not well known, and few viewers would put that medication and drinking together.

I will also state that many people, especially those who are alcoholics, rarely follow the precautions stated on medicine bottles and do as they please, even if there are severe consequences.